# Quasi-contractive semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I found in some articles the quasi-contraction semigroup notion. 
to proove the existence and uniqueness of the following Cauchy-problem $$\eqalign{
  & {{dU} \over {dt}} = AU  \cr 
  & U(0) = {U_0} \cr} $$
Instead of proving the usuel dissipation of the operator $A$ , they proved the dissipation of $A - cI$ ? is this gives us the same results of the usuel dissipation $(AU,U) \le 0$ ? Thank You.